# How to call correct class from URL Domain

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-variables

I have been currently working on creating a web crawler where I want to call the correct class that scrapes the web elements from a given URL.

Currently I have created:

```
import sys
import tldextract
import requests


class Scraper:
    scrapers = {}

    def __init_subclass__(scraper_class):
        Scraper.scrapers[scraper_class.url] = scraper_class

    @classmethod
    def for_url(cls, url):
        k = tldextract.extract(url)
        # return Scraper.scrapers[k.domain]()
        # or
        return cls.scrapers[k.domain]()


class BBCScraper(Scraper):
    url = 'bbc.co.uk'

    def scrape(s):
        print(s)
        # FIXME Scrape the correct values for BBC
        return "Scraped BBC News"


url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/'
scraper = Scraper.for_url(url)
scraper.scrape(requests.get(url))
```

What I am trying to do right now is that if the BBC is the domain name, then it should go into the `class BBCScraper(Scraper):` and since we call the `scraper.scrape(requests.get(url))` it should then scrape the web elements inside the `BBCScraper -> scrape -> Return web elements`

However I do have problems where i'm trying to run this script it outprints:

```
Outprint >>> return cls.scrapers[k.domain]() KeyError: 'bbc'
```

I wonder how I can call the correct class depending on the domain that has been given to the `for_url` classmethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `k.domain` returns `bbc` and you wrote `url = 'bbc.co.uk'` so one these solutions

- use `url = 'bbc.co.uk'` along with `k.registered_domain`
- use `url = 'bbc'` along with `k.domain`

And add a parameter in the `scrape` method to get the response

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
import requests
import tldextract

class Scraper:
    scrapers = {}

    def __init_subclass__(scraper_class):
        Scraper.scrapers[scraper_class.url] = scraper_class
    @classmethod
    def for_url(cls, url):
        k = tldextract.extract(url)
        return cls.scrapers[k.registered_domain]()
    @abstractmethod
    def scrape(self, content: requests.Response):
        pass

class BBCScraper(Scraper):
    url = 'bbc.co.uk'

    def scrape(self, content: requests.Response):
        return "Scraped BBC News"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/'
    scraper = Scraper.for_url(url)
    r = scraper.scrape(requests.get(url))
    print(r)  # Scraped BBC News
```

---

#### Improve

I'd suggest to store the `url` in a attribute to put the `requests.get` in the `scrape`, so there is less code in the main

```py
class Scraper:
    scrapers = {}

    def __init_subclass__(scraper_class):
        Scraper.scrapers[scraper_class.domain] = scraper_class

    @classmethod
    def for_url(cls, url):
        k = tldextract.extract(url)
        return cls.scrapers[k.registered_domain](url)

    @abstractmethod
    def scrape(self):
        pass


class BBCScraper(Scraper):
    domain = 'bbc.co.uk'

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def scrape(self):
        rep = requests.Response = requests.get(self.url)
        content = rep.text  # ALL HTML CONTENT
        return "Scraped BBC News" + content[:20]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/'
    scraper = Scraper.for_url(url)
    r = scraper.scrape()
    print(r)  # Scraped BBC News<!DOCTYPE html><html
```

Comment: Hi Azro! Seems like it works but I do get a warning on `Scraper.scrapers[scraper_class.domain] = scraper_class` where it says `Unresolved attribute reference 'domain' for class 'Scraper'` - Is it supposed to say so?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie did you change to `domain = 'bbc.co.uk'` ?

Comment: I did not, all I did was to copy paste the second code `Improve` that you have answered :D